# Aggregation for sorting with date using Spring data and mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have following records,

```
id   | date         | name
1    | 01/09/2017   | user1
2    | 02/09/2017   | user2
3    | 03/09/2017   | user3
```

I want the highest date record by aggregation query.
is it possible to use Sort method for the sorting the data records with date?
if yes how should I write the query ? 
is there any way to set the specific date format for sorting?

(I am using Spring data and mongoDB combination)
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of spring data but I can suggest that you should use an ISO date format for best results for date fields.

If you only need sorting then you can use "YYYY/MM/DD"("2017/12/04") format also.

In your case we can use "$split" ,"$reverseArray" ,"$concat" and "$arrayElemAt"

```
[
  {
     $addFields:{
      date:{$let:{
        vars:{rDate:{$reverseArray:{$split:["$date","/"]}}},
        in:{
        $concat:[{ $arrayElemAt: [ "$$rDate", 0] },"/",{ $arrayElemAt: [  "$$rDate", 1] },"/",{ $arrayElemAt: [ "$$rDate", 2] }]
        }
         }
      }
 }},
{
$sort:{
date:1
}
}
]
```